# Logstash can not handle multiple heterogeneous inputs

Tags: regex, logstash, elasticsearch

Let's say you have 2 very different types of logs such as FORTINET and NetASQ logs and you want:

grok FORTINET using a regex, ang grok NETASQ using an other regex.

I know that with "type"in the input file and "condition" in the filter we can resolve this problem.

So I used this confing file to do it :

```
input {
  file {
       type => "FORTINET"
       path => "/fortinet/*.log"
sincedb_path=>"/logstash-autre_version/var/.sincedb"
start_position => 'beginning'
  }
    file {
        type => "NETASQ"
        path => "/home/netasq/*.log"
   }
 } 
filter {
 if [type] == "FORTINET" {

        grok {
  patterns_dir => "/logstash-autre_version/patterns"

    match => [

    "message" , "%{FORTINET}"



    ]
    tag_on_failure => [ "failure_grok_exemple" ]
    break_on_match => false


    }


}

if [type] == "NETASQ" {
        # .......
 }
}


output {

elasticsearch {
cluster => "logstash"
}


}
```

And i'm getting this error :

```
Got error to send bulk of actions: no method 'type' for arguments(org.jruby.RubyArray) on Java::OrgElasticsearchActionIndex::IndexRequest   {:level=>:error}
```

But if don't use "type" and i grok only FORTINET logs it wroks.

What should i do ?

Comment: Your configuration looks perfectly fine. Are you sure you're not leaving out any pieces? No extra files in your /etc/logstash/conf.d?

Comment: this is the problem, my configuration is perfectly fine, and i don't know what's happened !

Comment: I suspect Logstash has additional configuration apart from what you've shown above.

Comment: Seems the error has to do with the output section of elasticsearch, not the input or the filter. Have you tried setting more parameters in the output, like index_type => %{type}?

Comment: no, before the configuration works well, I don't know  why it not works now !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but maybe it helps:

I have the same error and I think that it is caused by the use of these if statements:

```
if [type] == "FORTINET"
```

your `type` field is compared to `"FORTINET"` but this is maybe not possible because `"FORTINET"` is a string and `type` isn't. Some times by setting a type to an input, if there is already a type, the type isn't replaced, but the new type is added to a list with the old type. You should have a look to your data in kibana (or wherever) and try to find something like this:

```
\"type\":[\"FORTINET\",\"some-other-type\"]
```

maybe also without all those `\"` .
If you find something like this try not to set the type of your input explicitly and compare the `type` in your if-statement to the `some-other-type` you have found.

Hope this works (I'm working with more complex inputs/forwarders and for me it doesn't, but it is worth a try)